# magicline submenu hover not working

Tags: jquery, magicline

I am using magic line jquery, it works fine with main navigation but as soon as i add sub navigation, and if i hover it creates some issue and the lines moves back to first menu and does not stay to its parent.

Here is the code and codepen url, It creates issue because parent menu hover, so 
when hovering over submenu it loses it original position.

```
code here

<nav>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
       <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>

    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Really long string sample</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



body{font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:1em;overflow:hidden;min-height:325px}
nav{width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;}

/*Menu*/
ul.tabs{float:left;clear:both;width:800px;list-style:none;border-bottom:2px solid #00aeef;position:relative;font-size:1.061em;padding:0}
ul.tabs li{float:left}
ul.tabs li a{display:block;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;color:#666;padding:12px 20px;min-width:85px;font-weight:normal;transition: color 0.3s;}
ul.tabs li.active a{color:#00aeef}

#magic-line {position:absolute;bottom:-2px;left:0;width:125px;height:4px;background:#00aeef;transition: all 0.3s;}
/*Clear Fix*/
.tabs:after {visibility:hidden;display:block;content:"";clear:both;height:0}
*:first-child+html .tabs{zoom:1}

ul.submenu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    display: none;
}
li:hover ul.submenu { display:block;}
li { list-style:none;}


$(function() {
  'use strict';
  /*Activate default tab contents*/
  var leftPos, newWidth, $magicLine;

  $('.tabs').append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
  $magicLine = $('#magic-line');
  $magicLine.width($('.active').width())
    .css('left', $('.active a').position().left)
    .data('origLeft', $magicLine.position().left)
    .data('origWidth', $magicLine.width());

  $('.tabs li a').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    $magicLine
      .data('origLeft', $this.position().left)
      .data('origWidth', $this.parent().width());
    return false;
  });

  /*Magicline hover animation*/
  $('.tabs li').find('a').hover(function() {
    var $thisBar = $(this);
    leftPos = $thisBar.position().left;
    newWidth = $thisBar.parent().width();
    $magicLine.css({
      "left": leftPos,
      "width": newWidth
    });
  }, function() {
    $magicLine.css({
      "left": $magicLine.data('origLeft'),
      "width": $magicLine.data('origWidth')
    });
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/visha97243/pen/Xebpjx